# Angular2 filter array of objects

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, reactive-programming, rxjs5

i will start by adding the code, result i get and in the end what i would like to obtain and if it is possible.

The result which i'm getting  is Array[object, object, ...] where object is Array

```
export class SomeService {
           ....
           .... 
     public someFunction(): MyObject[]{
         Observable
            .forkJoin(this.userItemsA(userId), this.userItemsB(userId), etc)
             .filter(each => {
                      for (let array of each) {
                            let x: any = <any> array;
                               return x.length > 0;
                            }
                        })
             .map(result => {
                   return result;
              })
            .subscribe(result => {
                  /// what i would like to do for example assuming only 1st array has items
                  /// do something here with result[0] 
                  /// return MyObject[] from result[0]
        });
    ....
    }
}
```

> Filter structure

[image: filter structure]

I'm in my early learning stage of angular2 and reactive programming, what i would like is to filter so that the map result will be only the arrays that have at least 1 item.

Thank you

Comment: What's the structure of your data in `.filter(each => ...`?

Comment: i've uploaded the structure of the filter, thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `.filter` use `.map`

```
.map(each => {
    return each.filter(array => array.length > 0)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this doesn't work with `forkJoin`. What it does it joins several Observables into **single** Observable, thus if any of them is filtered out, the entire joined Observable get's interrupted/filtered.

As @Martin stated, you have to do your filtering in the `map` branch.